# how to retrieve in a loop More efficiency local storage getitem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

local data retrive multiple key value.Here is my code snippet this code is well but i need more efficiency in the loop.

```
<div id="anayzixe"></div>
<div id=uabza></div> 
<div id=mera></div>
<div id="mega"></div> 

<script>
  document.getElementyById().InnerHTML=localStorage.getItem("Ihram");
  document.getElementyById().InnerHTML=localStorage.getItem("meeqat");
  document.getElementyById().InnerHTML=localStorage.getItem("mina");
</script>
```

Convert into looping along with key value  remove against onpress button How it's???????????

Answer (score 0):

//you can get all the localstorage item by loop.

```
for(var i in localStorage)
{
    console.log(localStorage[i]);
}
```

//Lets say your HTML divs' id and localstorage items' keys are same then you can dynamically set the value. please refer following demo for more clarity.

```
localStorage.setItem('anayzixe', 'testing 1');
localStorage.setItem('uabza', 'testing 2');
localStorage.setItem('mera', 'testing 3');
localStorage.setItem('mega', 'testing 4');

for(var i in localStorage)
{
  console.log(localStorage[i]);
  document.getElementyById(i).InnerHTML=localStorage[i];

}
```

Comment: display on a html page

Comment: @ahmedghani if you want to display it in the HTML elements then the html element's id and localstorage items key must be same so you can make all dynamically.

Comment: Lets say your localstorage key and div's id are same then following code will be helpful to set localstorage value dynamically.

localStorage.setItem('anayzixe', 'testing 1');
localStorage.setItem('uabza', 'testing 2');
localStorage.setItem('mera', 'testing 3');
localStorage.setItem('mega', 'testing 4');

for(var i in localStorage)
{
  console.log(localStorage[i]);
  document.getElementyById(i).InnerHTML=localStorage[i];

}

Comment: how can identify div id dynamically

Comment: @ahmedghani set your div id and localstorage items' key same. So that when your are iterating loop for all localstorage item you can set that value to the div having id same as that item.